# ARKit – Adapting to light conditions

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am currently learning to do a few things ARKit in Unity and Swift.

Does anybody how can I adapt the light of my object to the environment light?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

> To enable ARKit's `Light Estimation` use this code:

- Enable Light Estimation in `viewDidLoad()` method:

  ```
  configuration.lightEstimationEnabled = true
  ```
- Exploit `lightEstimate.ambientIntensity` to update lighting:

  ```
  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, 
         updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

      guard let lightEstimate = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate 
      else { 
          return 
      } 
      spotLight.intensity = lightEstimate.ambientIntensity
  }
  ```

Also, you can read [THIS STORY](https://medium.com/@arkit/arkit-911-light-estimation-e10adf49ab32).